# Enviar dados post em file_get_contents

Tags: php, web-service

Boa tarde a todos, estou com o seguinte problema: Tenho que consumir de um WS que me retorna um Token, para usar de autenticação em outros WS. Para conseguir esse token eu tenho que enviar parametros via POST e recebo um JSON com o token. Eu consigo fazer isso usando o file_get_contents?
Eu tentei com o código abaixo, retirado da documentação do PHP, e não funcionou.

```
 $postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Porém meu result está dando apenas "false" e apresentando o erro: "file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in(...)"

Alguem sabe como resolver?

Comment: Eu já usei, sim é bem bacana por sinal.

Comment: @rray sabe me dizer se o codigo está correto? meu result está dando apenas false, e o erro "file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in"

Comment: Usa uma biblioteca chamada `GuzzleHttp`. É mais fácil do que ficar fazendo esse `file_get_contents`;)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters otima recomendação!

Comment: @rray você conhece também. Bacana ;)

Comment: utilize o curl... http://php.net/curl

Comment: @DanielOmine tentei utilizar o Curl mas o result continua a ser "false"

Comment: Tem certeza de que o endereço está correto? Observe  que a mensagem de erro informa erro de rede. Simplesmente não consegue obter informação do endereço. Pode ser 3 coisas óbvias, 1- algum problema ou bloqueio na rede onde está executando o scritpt; 2- bloqueio do destino; 3- destino inválido

Comment: @DanielOmine tenho certeza sim. Eu consegui fazer a mesma coisa, porém com JavaScript. E eu utilizo o Postman pra testar os requests também, e está tudo ok com o endereço

Comment: isso não faz sentido.. qual erro apresentado no curl?

Comment: apenas result = false

Answer (score 1):

O erro "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known", costuma acontecer quando tentamos usar a função stream_get_contents ou file_get_contents e passamos uma url no parâmetro.

Em alguns casos tambem apresenta este mesmo problema com sistemas de email.

A verdade é que em 90% dos casos, o problema está na configuração do nameserver!

Siga os passos, para corrigir esse problema:

1 - Acesse o servidor via SSH
2 - Depois digitar

```
#nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Colocar os IPs do Google nos nameservers.

Exemplo:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

E diga adeus ao erro "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

Tirei daqui: 
https://wp.me/p8Hv3H-1p

https://blog.hospedamais.com/servidor/resolvendo-o-erro-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/